# How was the opening scene in Fight Club made?

Tags: effects, fight-club

In the opening scene of Fight Club (1999) there is a visual journey through the Narrator's brain showing the "synapses". How was that scene made?

Comment: But you're Tyler Durden ... you should know this, right? J/K! Probably just CGI, but hopefully someone has a good answer for you.

Comment: Looks like pure CGI to me

Comment: I think there is a good commentary on it on the DVD, but don't have access to it now unfortunately. Pretty sure its CGI, the Movie was groundbreaking in that respect - lots of previously 'impossible' shots, like how his apartment was blown up, or the pull-back from the wastepaper basket.

Comment: I was hoping for a more detailed answer than "CGI". I mean it looks pretty detailed like it was made by somebody who actually knows a brain looks like at the microscopic level. There must an interesting story there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scene was shot using extensive CGI, and this was during a period in which David Fincher was not only exploring the use of 'impossible shots', but pioneering new techniques...

The film used [texture mapping](http://www.filmsite.org/visualeffects18.html) and matte painting combined with CGI to achieve previously unseen special effects, as the first motion picture to use [Photogrammetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry).

[image]

Comment: That is pretty cool. I was specifically interested in how they modelled the brain, although I guess nowadays that kind of CGI would be considered routine, back then it was really astonishing.